# Send e-mail with ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT

Tags: python, ssl

I wrote some code to send e-mails over a relay in Python. The code can be seen below. I have marked variables like which I changed from the real code in {}:

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 587  # For TLS

# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

with smtplib.SMTP({relay_name}, port) as server:
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.login({from_mail}, {password})
    server.sendmail({from_mail},{to_mail}, message)
```

This works without a problem, but I get a warning:

```
 DeprecationWarning: ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 is deprecated
```

Now I have taken studied the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#module-ssl) for quite a while and it seems that I should be using *ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT* instead of *ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2*, but I cannot really figure out how this would work. The simple way by just replacing the protocols does not work as I than get an  error:

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I assume that to make it work I need a line similar to `context.load_verify_locations('path/to/cabundle.pem')` as written in one of the examples in the documentation but I am unsure which .pem file I can and should use here.
Do I need a file for which the public key is then deployed on the relay? Can I just create any .pem file? Why then did it work before without that. I have read somewhere that the base version uses same kind of default certificate how can I use this here?

Comment: If I look at the documentation then you get: "# PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT requires valid cert chain and hostname". That's probably indicating *client* authentication where the client also authenticates itself using an X.509certificate and private key to the server. If that's not explicitly what you require then you should not use it: you seem to be using username / password for authentication.